# Tailwind CSS Border bottom moving last element

Tags: tailwind-css

Trying to add a custom underline hover effect using Tailwind.

```
<div className='absolute left-24 space-x-4 hidden lg:flex font-light'>
               <p className='hover:border-b-2 border-blue-500 -mb-1'>Find jobs</p>
               <p className='hover:border-b-2 border-blue-500 -mb-1 '>Company Reviews</p>
               <p className='hover:border-b-2 border-blue-500 '> Find salaries</p>
               </div>
```

It works for the first two when -mb-1 is added, but when the 'Find Salaries' hovers over the text moves up by a few px. Tried added MB or -MB but still no luck.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing the border-width you could change border-color, then there's no moving parts.

```
<div class='space-x-4 font-light'>
  <p class='border-b-2 hover:border-blue-500 border-transparent'>Find jobs</p>
  <p class='border-b-2 !m-0 hover:border-blue-500 border-transparent '>Company Reviews</p>
  <p class='border-b-2 !m-0 hover:border-blue-500 border-transparent'> Find salaries</p>
</div>
```